# How can I change the synthetic conditions for powder product into single crystal growth?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

I am working on growing metal-organic frameworks crystals based on hexatopic linker for different metals. Upon using some synthetic conditions it gave fast precipitation into powder material after heating for half hour. My question is how to modulate the synthesis to grow single crystals for Zr, Fe, Al in my case? I used metal salt:linker as 10:1 using modulator 100 equivalent to metal salt.

Comment: Conditions optimal for *seeding* crystallization needn't to be the optimum ones for crystal *growth*.  Attempt to seed slowier (e.g., less concentrated reagents, slower addition) than "crushing out"; warm a little to moderate growth.  If aiming for a crystal structure determination and still *less lucky*, you still may opt for microfocus instruments (e.g., https://www.diamond.ac.uk/Instruments/Techniques/Diffraction/Microfocus#), electron diffraction (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_crystallography) or general powder diffraction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powder_diffraction).

Comment: You, as far synthesis as the common meaning, won't attain a single crystal directly. The fact that you are working with framework complicate things as for it is possible that the standard way of growing crystal won't work. Else normally one prepare diluted solution in clean glassware and wait for solvent evaporation in a vibration free corner of the building. If you are dealing with crystal determination specialist can cut single crystals out of big enough not perfect crystals.